# Insert an paragraph with jQuery in an PHP 'If' statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've written a simple login script that connects to a db, and now I want to insert a paragraph with jQuery in my #loginbox which says 'Login failed' when

```
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

is true.

My thought was:

**[function.js]**

```
function loginfailed() {
    $('#loginbox').html("<p>Login failed.</p>");
}
```

**[login.php]**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>

<?php
    include '../config.php';
    include 'dbh.php';

    session_start();

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pw='$pw'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        header('Location: ../index.php');

        echo '<script> loginfailed(); </script>';
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Firstly, you are storing passwords in plaintext. This is **VERY BAD**. Secondly, you should be using prepared statements - you are currently vulnerable to very simple SQL injection which would allow someone to log in as any user they wished.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use jQuery /  javascript to add this text when you are using PHP to render the html already?

Comment: I know this script is not secure, but it is only for exercise. But thanks for this.

Comment: @scythe when you have the power to render the html on the server like you have here, you would want to just echo "Login failed" instead of including javascript/jQuery at all

Comment: Okay, but consider the consequences of someone entering the value `admin' -- ` as their username (particularly what the value of `$sql` ends up as).

Comment: Thanks Stian, but i already now this. 
I repeat it is just for exercise.

Answer (score 1):

**DON'T EVER STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT!!**
Regarding your question.
The header function redirects to index.php and does not execute the echo. One solution can be to add a $_GET parameter and after the redirect check if it exists and echo the message or append it with JS.

```
 if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        header('Location: ../index.php?status=fail');

    }
```

In the `index.php` file at the bottom (if you want to use JS/jQuery to show message)

```
<script>
var status = "<?php echo (!empty($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] === 'fail') ? 0 : 1; ?>";
if(!status) loginfailed();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but i've found my own solution with the help of Allkin.

My header now redirects to

```
header('Location: ../index.php?status=fail');
```

and my #loginbox checks if status is set and then executes my loginfailed() function.

```
if(isset($_GET['status'])) {
    echo '<script> loginfailed(); </script>';
}
```

Nothing easy like that!

Thanks for your help everyone.